# GWT maps v3 missing drawinglib?

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, drawing

I have gwt-maps-3.0.2b.gwt22.jar, but I wanted to test code from http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maps-api/source/browse/trunk/Apis_Maps_Test/src/com/gonevertical/maps/testing/client/maps/DrawingMapWidget.java. I have problem, because my IDE saied me unknown imports:

```
import com.google.gwt.maps.client.drawinglib.DrawingControlOptions;
import com.google.gwt.maps.client.drawinglib.DrawingManager;
import com.google.gwt.maps.client.drawinglib.DrawingManagerOptions;
import com.google.gwt.maps.client.drawinglib.OverlayType;
```

I dont know to find some documentation. I dont understand that Do I need some another libraries or jar files ? How do I use drawing libraries in GWT Java ?

Answer (score 0):

The JAR file you have (gwt-maps-3.0.2b.gwt22.jar) is from this project: [gwt-google-maps-v3](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/). However, the sample code you are trying to use is from this project: [gwt-maps-api](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maps-api).  These are different projects and the example from gwt-maps-api won't compile against the gwt-google-maps-v3 library.

If you really want to use the example code from the gwt-maps-api project, you will need to also download the rest of it as a library and import it into your project somehow.  This is probably going to be hard since the library is only in an alpha state currently, and the author has not packaged it yet.